# SQL group by if columnA is equal to columnB

Tags: sql, group-by

I have the following SQL table:

```
+--------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+
| flow_number  | src_ip         | dst_ip         | date                |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+
|           1  | 1.1.1.1.1      | 192.168.2.218  | 2022-11-01 16:00:10 |
|           10 | 192.168.2.218  | 1.1.1.1        | 2022-11-01 16:00:12 |
```

I would like to be able to combine both to a single record in case src_ip == dst_ip. So would like to get the following result:

```
+-------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+
| flow_number | src_ip         | dst_ip         | date                |
+-------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+
|          11 | 1.1.1.1        | 192.168.2.218  | 2022-11-01 16:00:12 |
```

So basically i should sum flow_number across aggregated records and choose any date. It also does not matter which ip address will be selected as "src_ip" versus "dst_ip". Which means the following results are also acceptable:

```
+-------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+
| flow_number | src_ip         | dst_ip         | date                |
+-------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------+
|          11 | 192.168.2.218  | 1.1.1.1        | 2022-11-01 16:00:10 |
```

Tried with MD5 and CONCAT few options. Tried to add two new columns (hashes) of `src_ip+dst_ip` and `dst_ip+src_ip`:

```
SELECT *,MD5(CONCAT(src_ip,dst_ip)) as hash1, MD5(CONCAT(dst_ip,src_ip)) as hash2 FROM
(SELECT COUNT(*) as flow_number,src_ip,dst_ip,date 
FROM flows 
GROUP BY src_ip, dst_ip) AS T1
```

But still can not group based on a different columns.

How to solve this problem ?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Do you have the queries you have tried?  You can try a self join to the same table on that column.

Comment: is it coincidence that flow number is the same in the two records ... and date is the same too! And how did you decide that the new flow_number would be `2`

Comment: What engine are you using? SQL Server? MySQL? etc. Also, as @topsail pointed out, if flow_number is 3 and 3 will it combine to be 6?... can there be more than 2 rows per flow #?

Comment: sorry - was not very precise, now it should be more clear (edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using `MySQL` since you tried using `MD5()`:

You can use `SUM()` with a `CROSS JOIN` to get the [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of every `flow_id` in the table by doing a `self-join` using the `src_ip` and `dst_ip` along with a `CTE` to generate a `ROW_NUMBER()` (selecting only the first row number).

```
WITH CTE AS
  (SELECT 
  d.flow_number,  
  b.src_ip,
  b.dst_ip,
  a.date,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY d.flow_number) AS RN
FROM flows a
   INNER JOIN flows b ON a.src_ip = b.dst_ip AND b.src_ip = a.dst_ip
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 
      SUM(a.flow_number) flow_number
    FROM flows a
      INNER JOIN flows b ON a.src_ip = b.dst_ip AND b.src_ip = a.dst_ip
) d)
SELECT 
  flow_number,  
  src_ip,
  dst_ip,
  date
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

**Result:**

```
| flow_number | src_ip    | dst_ip        | date                |
|-------------|-----------|---------------|---------------------|
| 11          | 1.1.1.1.1 | 192.168.2.218 | 2022-11-01 16:00:12 |
```

Change `RN = 1` to `RN = 2` to get the opposite result set.

```
| flow_number | src_ip        | dst_ip    | date                |
|-------------|---------------|-----------|---------------------|
| 11          | 192.168.2.218 | 1.1.1.1.1 | 2022-11-01 16:00:10 |
```

**Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/6DpmixGX).**